# Pascal Script Round using Bitwise/other operators

Tags: delphi, operators, bit-manipulation, rounding

EDIT:

Using **shl**, **MOD**, **DIV**, **shr**, or any other operators. I can't get conditionals to work.

In a constant round up an extended number e.g.

const
     aaa = 3.14;
     bbb = 3.14; // round this one up

Comment: Why? If you want the *constant* to be an integer, why don't you declare it with the value you want? My memory is blurry (it was almost a decade ago since I worked  with delphi) but can't you cast it to an int? Delphi compiles the code, and IIRC it will inlinte the code if it make sense. But I still don't understand why you don't wand to use the built in functions? Why?!?

Comment: I do not think you can cast to an int in the constant declaration. Why? Because I want to work with relative constants. e.g. const aaa = 5.14; const bbb = aaa // and round this somehow

Comment: Have you tried to use trunc(), round(), floor() or ceil() ? Another way that could work (not tested) would be `(...calculations...) div 1`.

Comment: This compiler doesn't support them in constants. I don't think there is anyway around this. Those functions are available for a reason I guess.

Comment: What compiler are you using then?

Comment: Take X, and round it up or down using Delphi. Using just bitwise, operators, and no function calls. It might be possible but looks a little hard.

Comment: Its either PaxCompiler, or PascalScript. Both of which might not be in the delphi category, but w/e.

Comment: aaa = (3.14 or 0); type mismatch on that line

Comment: aaa = (3.14 = 1); That works though and < > I think you can accomplish this with assembly...

Comment: This works too, shift left, and shift right bitwise. aaa = 4 shl 4; that gives 64 on debug

Comment: @TristanL.: Is casting a `Double` to `Int64` possible in your compiler?

Comment: I tried with [freepascal](http://www.freepascal.org) and there it works with `trunc()` and `round()` in the constant.

Comment: The bitwise operators work on ordinal types (eg., integer, char, byte), and not on floating point values. You'll need to `Trunc` or `Round` the value first before you can use bitwise ops.

Comment: Okay, well it seems you can't cast anything to a type. Tried double, int64, and others

Comment: Maybe I should just variables instead for some things and others I can just use constants. I don't see a way around this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one would use `trunc()` or `round()`. If that doesn't work for you I suggest that you try to find a forum that specializes PaxCompiler, or PascalScript. You can't be the first one that wants to do this, and someone that is more familiar with these compilers might know how to solve the problem with these compilers.

I tried it in [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org) and there it works. IIRC it works in Borland Delphi and Turbo Pascal too (it was several years since I programmed in pascal so I could be wrong).

If none of the above works, then you might try to put it in a global variable. Even if global variables is bad, it is sometimes the least bad thing to do.